# Segmentation fault 11 in a Practice

Tags: c++, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I'm working on an exercise for my Algorithms class and I'm getting a `segmentation fault:11` in `line 58` and I don't know why, I mean, I know that the first call to function "localiza" works fine but the second one,

```
*i2 = localiza(v2, 0, v2.size())*
```

provokes the segmentation fault and I don't know why.
This algorithm is used for find an index such that `v[i] = i`. In `main()`, if `i1` and `i2` are `!= 0` means that `v1[i1] = i1` and `v2[i2] = i2`.
I hope you could help me with the exercise. Lot of thanks guys!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int localiza(vector <int> v, int primero, int ultimo){
    int i = 0;
    int izq = 0, der = 0;

    if(primero == ultimo)
        if (v[primero] == primero)
            return primero;
        else 
            return 0; // No existe el indice buscado
    else{
        i = (primero + ultimo) / 2; // Division entera

        if(v[i] == i)
            return i;
        else if(v[i] > i){
            izq = localiza(v, primero, i-1); // Primera mitad

            if(v[i] <= ultimo)
                der = localiza(v, v[i], ultimo);
            else
                der = 0;

            if(izq != 0)
                return izq;
            else if(der != 0)
                return der;
            else 
                return 0;
        }
        else{
            der = localiza(v, i+1, ultimo);

            if(primero <= v[i])
                izq = localiza(v, primero, v[i]);
            else 
                izq = 0;

            if(der != 0)
                return der;
            else if(izq != 0)
                return izq;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    vector <int> v1 = {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11};
    vector <int> v2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 15, 16};

    int i1 = localiza(v1, 0, v1.size());
    int i2 = localiza(v2, 0, v2.size());

    if(i1 != 0)
        cout << "Si existe el indice indicado para el primer vector";
    else
        cout << "No existe el indice indicado para el primer vector";

    if(i2 != 0)
        cout << "Si existe el indice indicado para el segundo vector";
    else
        cout << "No existe el indice indicado para el segundo vector";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: It looks like your function is treating `ultimo` as the last valid index, but you're passing the size of the vector at first.

Answer (score 1):

Your accessing `v` using `[]` is causing an out of bounds access. The rot sets in since you are passing the size of the vectors as a potential upper limit.

If you use `v.at(i)` rather than `v[i]` then C++ is required to throw an exception on such an occasion, rather than the program behaviour being undefined. Then you'll be able to fix the problem as the cause will be explicit.

Comment: I changed every [] with v.at(i) but I'm getting the same error

Comment: @ixjosemi: Of course you will. But the error is *well-defined*. Now you are in a position to fix it! Did you not read the rest of my answer?

Comment: @ixjosemi Protip: if you use GCC or Clang, you can pass `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` as a compilation flag to get systematic bounds checking with well-defined failures without changing your code.

Comment: @ixjosemi *but I'm getting the same error* -- That is not true.  You are getting a different error, a `std::out_of_range` exception, not a segmentation fault.  Now see which `at()` call threw that exception by stepping through your program with a debugger.